# MySQL convert legacy decimal to milliseconds

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I am working with some legacy tables that represent time as a decimal representating time like this:

```
74447.548  = 7:44:47.548
```

I am moving this to a table where time is stored as (int) milliseconds.   I want to create a function for this conversion..   The following works, but is there a more efficient way??

```
CREATE FUNCTION `test`.`decimalToMilli` (bigTime decimal)
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
return (floor(mod(bigTime,floor(bigTime))*1000)  -- milliseconds
  + (floor(bigTime) MOD 100)  * 1000 -- seconds
  + ((((floor(bigTime) - floor(bigTime) MOD 100) MOD 10000))/100) * 1000*60  -- minutes
  + ((((floor(bigTime) - floor(bigTime) MOD 10000) MOD 1000000))/10000) * 1000*60*60 --hrs
);
END
```

Suggestions for a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
CREATE FUNCTION `test`.`decimalToMilli` (bigTime decimal)
RETURNS INTEGER
BEGIN
  return ((bigTime * 1000) MOD 100000  -- seconds and milliseconds
         + (floor(bigTime / 100) MOD 100) * 60000 --minutes
         + (floor(bigTime / 10000)) * 3600000 -- hours
         );
END
```

Comment: Thanks - but I just found on my testing that both your and my routines round the milliseconds to the nearest second?!?

Comment: A value of 2032.808 is inserted into my table as 1233000 rather than 1232808  - I am using this in a trigger as  raw_time=decimalToMilli(NEW.CumulativeTime),

Comment: Ah - it was in the declaration of the bigTime...   It should be (bigTime decimal (12,6))